# Should I use for this case a transaction?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I develop a personal management application and the people can select mulitple days and users and can choose a time when he was to work. So maybe a problem occurs or the user makes a double call then I then I have double rows in my database but that shouldnt happen.

So whats the best way to prevent it ?

I can select all userids and start_time and end_time and then check if any rows exists and this works but if I make two times concurrent request then this not working.

Now my question is should I make a transaction and use SELECT FOR UPDATE to lock this row ? Is this fine in this use case or is there another solution ?

Comment: Use a range data type, tsrange, in combination with an exclusion constraint. That makes it impossible to create conflicting appointments. See the manual for an example: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT

Answer (score 1):

The best way of avoiding duplicate rows in a table is usually to get the database to enforce it by creating a unique index on relevant columns. This guarantees no duplicates on those columns in the table, irrespective of concurrent updates etc. Your app then has to handle errors that are raised if it tries to insert a row that already exists.

If for some reason that's not going to work for you then start thinking about SELECT FOR UPDATE. (But possibly only after thinking about redesigning your database so that unique indexes *do* work)